# Finding squares that add to a certain sum

Tags: square-numbers, sums-of-squares

I have been looking for an algebraic way to solve for 2 squares when given a sum, but I got nothing so far.

For example:

$$y^2 + x^2 = 9797$$

I thought that the solution would have to do something like this, but I want a method which is certain to give me a solution without trial and error.

$$f(x) = \sqrt{(9797 - x^2)}$$

or this where I would just increase the variable a by one until x^2 is a perfect square.

$$9797 - y^2 = x^2$$

I came across the sum of two squares theorem, as well Fermat's theorem on sums of two squares. However, they state that a number can be written as $x^2 + y^2 = z$ but from my research, I believe they did not state a solution to solve the two squares.

Edit: I wanted to add that I know there can be multiple solutions to problem, as the example I gave has $4$ solutions.

Comment: an article from about 1990 by Stan Wagon, called The Euclidean Algorithm Strikes Again. https://www.jstor.org/stable/2323912?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents

Comment: I gave an answer for primes at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1521776/express-prime-as-sum-of-squares-p-a2-b2?rq=1

Comment: here is one that discusses composite numbers https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1471878/sum-of-two-squares-n-a2-b2-where-n-is-not-prime?rq=1

Comment: This is possible only for certain sums by Fermat's two squares theorem.

Answer (score 0):

$$x^2+y^2=9797\implies y=\sqrt{9797-x^2}\\
\implies\bigg\lceil\sqrt{9797-\big(\big\lfloor\sqrt{9797}\;\big\rfloor\big)^2}\space \bigg\rceil=14\le
 x\le \big\lfloor\sqrt{9797}\;\big\rfloor=98$$
This shows a finite search and any $\space x \space $ that yields an integer $\space y\space $ is a solution.
Since $\space x,y\space $ are interchangeable, this means
$\qquad|x|,|y|\in\big\{31,49,86,94\big\}\qquad$ with the valid solutions being combinations of the pairs $\space 31,94\space $ and $\space 49,86\space $ for a total of $\space  16\space $ solutions.

Note: The reason that the ends and middles of the set are paired is because the farthest and nearest members must be paired in the same way that $\space 100,1\space $ and $\space 51,50\space $ would be paired to sum integers. If paired otherwise, their squares summed would be smaller or larger than $\space 9797.\space $